# Using Asp.Net Membership across sites

Tags: asp.net, web-services, authentication, asp.net-membership

I have multiple(17) sites on Production, which uses ASP.Net Membership to store user credentials, now i am planning to create a common web-service which will be accepting the username and the site name and would return me the password in the plain text, the user consuming web-service is authorized.

Now i want to know how can i get the password using the ASP.Net membership, Is there any way i can pass the ASP.Net Membership provider as per the site and with that in place i would be able to retrieve password.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Why do you want the web service to return the password in plain text? That is very insecure.

Comment: i know but thats the client requirement, they want to know the password based on username, and also the web-service consumption will be limited to client only so no probs

Comment: Maybe at least encrypt the password with a private key that only the client has?